# How can I test with rspec different routes but to the same controller method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I can explain.

On my routes I have this:

```
resources :questions, :path => 'pq', only: [:index, :show, :create] do
  #many other routes...
  member do
    post :up_vote, action: :vote, vote: 1
    post :down_vote, action: :vote, vote: -1
  end
end
```

You can observe, it has two routes for the same action, but send a param 'vote' for both.

I tried test with rspec using:

```
before{ post :up_vote, id: 1 }
```

Or

```
before{ post :vote, id: 1, vote: 1 }
```

But I haven't no success, always returns `No routes matches`

Anyone know how can I test with rspec it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your `only` clause on the `resources` line and retest.